# why jsp page waits for user input when if statement is used

Tags: jsp, user-input

when i use code for getting username from user

and when i use if(str!=null) then it waits for user input and when i remove if statement it prints UserName Not Valid Or Does Not Exist!!! immediately why this happens

```
    <%

        String str1=request.getParameter("username");
        String str2=request.getParameter("type");
        if(str1!=null)
        {
                int flag=0;

        try{
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection c=                                                                                                    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","pass"); 
                            Statement s= c.createStatement();
                    if(str2 == "student")
              {
          String sql="select pass from student where username='"+str1+"'";
                ResultSet rs= s.executeQuery(sql);
                if(rs.next())
                    flag=1;
                else
                    flag=0;

                if(flag==1)
                {
                out.println("YOUR PASSWORD IS "+rs.getString(2)+"!!!");
                }
                else
                out.println("UserName Not Valid Or Does Not Exist!!!");
                rs.close();
            }
            else
            {
            String sql1="select pass from faculty where username='"+str1+"'";
                ResultSet rs1= s.executeQuery(sql1);
                if(rs1.next())
                    flag=1;
                else
                    flag=0;

                if(flag==1)
                {
                out.println("YOUR PASSWORD IS "+rs1.getString(2)+"!!!");
                }
                else
                out.println("UserName Not Valid Or Does Not Exist!!!");
                rs1.close();
            }
            s.close();
            c.close();
            }catch(Exception e) {  out.println(e);}
        }
    %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of the page, I am guessing that this is the code at the top of a page that does the processing as well as takes the input of a form. So if you load the page when it doesn't have the if() statement, then it immediately attempts to query the database with a query that will return nothing. When it goes into the if ( rs.next() ) it will return false. So the flag is set to 0 and then your message immediately prints. Again, this is just a guess without seeing the rest of the page.